# Изменить параметр css c помощью js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Я делаю небольшой календарь событий. Есть формы для ввода события, его описания, ввода даты и времени начала и даты и времени конца. Для однодневного события я добавил checkbox, при нажатии на который форма для ввода даты и времени конца должна скрываться, и появляться по снятию галочки.
*Вот код формы:*

```
<%= form_for(event) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Событие %>
    <%= f.text_field :event %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Описание %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <%= check_box_tag(:one_day)%>
    <%= label_tag("однодневное")%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Дата_начала %>
    <%= f.date_field :date_start %>
    <%= f.time_field :time_start %>
  </div>

  <div class="field" id="datetime_end" style="display:done;">
    <%= f.label :Дата_конца %>
    <%= f.date_field :date_end %>
    <%= f.time_field :time_end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Во-первых, в чём, собственно, вопрос? Во-вторых, рельсы тут не при чём. Лучше заменить `erb`-код результирующим `HTML` и убрать метку `ruby-on-rails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var oneday = document.getElementById("oneday")
oneday.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if (oneday.checked) {
    document.getElementById("datetime_start").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("datetime_end").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("datetime_start").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("datetime_end").style.display = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <lable>Event</lable>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="field">
  <lable>Описание</lable>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <lable>однодневное</lable>
  <input type="checkbox" id="oneday">
</div>

<div class="field" id="datetime_start">
  <lable>Дата_начала</lable>
  <input type="date">
  <input type="date">
</div>

<div class="field" id="datetime_end">
  <lable>Дата_конца</lable>
  <input type="date">
  <input type="date">
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: ваше решение не учитывает фреймворк. пожалуйста исправьте. вот тут вы можете прочитать как правильно использовать JavaScript и jQuery в фреймворке http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

С использованием jQuery:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $("#datetime_end").toggle(this.unchecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isOneDay"/>
<div id="datetime_end" >
  сontent
</div>
```

Comment: ваше решение не учитывает фреймворк. пожалуйста исправьте.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman так лучше?

Comment: вот тут вы можете прочитать как правильно использовать JavaScript и jQuery в фреймворке http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, почитаю.